# How to pick n smallest numbers from a list with nested lists as elements

Tags: python, list, function

Consider the following code:

```
def temporary4(ratio,x,y):
  results = [] 
  for x in range(1,x):
    results.append(abs((1200*math.log((2**(x/y)),2)-(1200*math.log(ratio,2))))) 
  return results
def intApprox(ratio,x):
  return min(temporary4(ratio,x,x))
```

Now I use that to make a function that makes a list with a list of 2 elements as elements.

```
def temporaryTempFinder(ratio):
  list1 = []
  for x in range(12,61,1):
    list1.append([intApprox(ratio,x),x])
  return list1
```

Test:

```
temporaryTempFinder(3/2)
```

This returns a list with terms that look like:

```
[[1.955000865387433, 12],
 [36.50653759615102, 13],
 [16.240715151101654, 14],
 [18.044999134612567, 15],
 [26.95500086538732, 16],
 [3.927352075789031, 17],
 [31.37833246794594, 18],
 [7.218158760124197, 19],
 [18.044999134612567, 20],
 [16.240715151101654, 21],
 [7.135908225521689, 22],
 [23.69413130017017, 23],
 [1.955000865387433, 24],
 [18.044999134612567, 25],
 [9.647308557695169, 26],
 [9.156110245723653, 27],
 [16.240715151101654, 28],
 [1.4932749966815209, 29],
 [18.044999134612567, 30],
 [5.180807317000472, 31],
 [10.54499913461268, 32],
 [11.045909956296327, 33],
 [3.927352075789031, 34],
 [16.240715151101654, 35],
 [1.955000865387433, 36],
 [11.558512648126111, 37],
 [7.218158760124197, 38],
 [5.737306826920303, 39],
 [11.95500086538732, 40],
 [0.484023524856525, 41],
 [12.330713420327015, 42],
 [4.280582260736196, 43],
 [7.135908225521689, 44],
 [8.621667532054175, 45],
 [2.3928252215692964, 46],
 [12.593298737727878, 47],
 [1.955000865387433, 48],
 [8.249080767265582, 49],
 [5.95500086538766, 50],
 [3.927352075789031, 51],
 [9.647308557695169, 52],
 [0.06820841255716914, 53],
 [9.156110245723653, 54],
 [3.7731826835693028, 55],
 [5.187856277469905, 56],
 [7.218158760124197, 57],
 [1.4932749966815209, 58],
 [9.90940591427352, 59],
 [1.955000865387433, 60]]
```

I successfully made a function that picks the element with the smallest first element from the list and returns the second element of the element:

```
def topTempFinder(ratio):
  list1 = []
  for x in range(12,61,1):
    list1.append([intApprox(ratio,x),x])
  return min(list1)[1]

topTempFinder(3/2)
```

The Result:

```
53
```

This is desired because the element which has `53` as its second element has the smallest first element (`0.06820841255716914`) (refer to the list above for clarification).

My issue now is that I am trying to pick the top 10 elements with the smallest first element and I want the function to return a list of the SECOND element of the chosen elements.

My attempt:

```
def temporaryTempFinder2(ratio):
  list1 = []
  for x in range(12,61,1):
    list1.append(intApprox(ratio,x))
  return list1

def top10TempFinder(list1):
    final_list = []
  
    for i in range(0, 10): 
        min1 = 100
          
        for j in range(len(list1)):     
            if list1[j] < min1:
                min1 = list1[j];
                  
        list1.remove(min1);
        final_list.append(min1)
          
    return final_list

list1 = temporaryTempFinder(3/2)
list2 = temporaryTempFinder2(3/2)
```

Trying the code:

```
top10TempFinder(list2)
top10TempFinder(list1)
```

Here is where the issue comes, when I use `list2`, it works as the list has elements without nested lists, however, with `list1` I get the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

I would like to know how to deal with this.
I apologize if the language was confusing and hard to follow, I have attempted to provide examples to make things clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`sorted()`](https://realpython.com/python-sort/#sorted-with-a-key-argument) built-in function from python with a key argument or [`heapq.nsmallest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) function from python's standard library.

#### `.sorted()` solution

```
>>> temp = temporaryTempFinder(3/2)
>>> def top10(arr):
...     return [i[1] for i in sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[0])[:10]]
... 
>>> top10(temp)
[53, 41, 29, 58, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 46]
```

#### `heapq.nsmallest()` solution

```
>>> import heapq
>>> def top10(arr):
...     return [i[1] for i in heapq.nsmallest(10, arr)]
... 
>>> top10(temp)
[53, 41, 29, 58, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 46]
```

Comment: `heapq.nsmallest` seems to be much faster for large lists

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this would be to turn your list into a dict then sort that.

```
info = {l[1]:l[0] for l in lst}
info = dict(sorted(info.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
print(list(info.keys())[:10])
```

output

```
[53, 41, 29, 58, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 46]
```

#Note: lst is your list.